# Webserver timing out

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, apache2, wordpress, webmin

I was working with my website yesterday when I was at home using my web address. Yesterday I installed Wordpress and it seemed to work.

When I got to work today, I tried opening my website, and now the connection times out. I can still access my Virtualmin interface, just not the actual website.

What could cause this, as I had made no changes to Virtualmin since it was working yesterday.

Note: I have also restarted my server to try and resolve the issue.

```
Site: www.weekshouse.com
Server: Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS)
CMS: Wordpress
```

Comment: Is there anything in Apeche's error log?

Comment: The only thing in the error log is: `[Wed May 09 00:09:51 2012] [error] [client 174.61.209.88] File does not exist: /home/weekshouse/public_html/favicon.ico`

Answer (score 2):

I just did a DNS lookup on both weekshouse.com and www.weekshouse.com.

Here are my findings:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.weekshouse.com
Address: 174.61.209.88
```

This is registered under Comcast.

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   weekshouse.com
Address: 174.129.88.121
```

This is registered under Amazon.

My thoughts are, that you currently use Amazon to append the www to the domain, and are trying to host it from your house? If it is from your house, then make sure that IP address is correct.

I just think it's a small error somewhere along the line of not updating old information, which is confusing the visitors' browsers.

Also pinging it fails:

```
root@dev:/# ping www.weekshouse.com
PING www.weekshouse.com (174.61.209.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.weekshouse.com ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13103ms
```

My final conclusion is that perhaps you have a different IP address today? (http://icanhazip.com from your house to check).
**Your IP address in regards to how I found it before is public information already. If you want me to remove it from this post, please tell me.**

Comment: There may just be a problem with No-IP.com's system. It was supposed to show as a redirect to www.weekshouse.com. I did however make the changes to the record to return an A record instead. The problem still exists though.

Comment: You should have your A-record set to your house's IP address, and make SURE that port 80 is open and listening, and that on the server, apache is running and not failing to bind to the port, and that you can access the site from your local network. I'm still failing to ping your raw IP address, so I think your issue is internal (it resolves thru no-ip just fine).